# mbed webserver crashing because of memcpy

Tags: c, arrays, microcontroller, memcpy, mbed

I used FRDM-K64F microcontroller to create a webserver using C language.My webserver is offering a web page with some text boxes and display msgs. My next challenge was to store  ip addresses  and bit srteams provided by the user.

I created two global arrays ipaddr[3][17] and bits[3][17] to store the bits and ipaddresses, i now want to increase the size of the array, but i observed if i increase the size of array even ipaddr[4][17], it  crashes my webserver. following is the code which copies the user provided string to the arrays.

```
void testFunc(char * str)
{    
    char *ht="://";  
    char *ur="/cgi-bin/ext/e_alarm.cgi?zone=0";   
    char *ip;  //ip address to be stored from the user

    ip = new char[15];

    char *pch; //use for tokenizing the string
    char *htt; //combining the strings
    char *b; //bits to be stored from the user

    b = new char [6];

    if(strstr(str,"trigger") != NULL)
    { 
        //ip1="http://192.168.0.233/cgi-bin/ext/e_alarm.cgi?zone=0";
        RED_ON; GREEN_OFF; BLUE_OFF; 

        pch = strtok (str,"&=");

        ip = pch;

        pch = strtok (NULL, "&=");
        pch = strtok (NULL, "&=");

        b = pch;

        pch = strtok (NULL, "=");

        htt = pch;

        strcat(htt, ht); 

        strcat(htt, ip);  
        strcat(htt, ur);  

        printf("htt is %s \n",htt);

        memcpy(ipaddr[counter], ip, strlen(ip));
        memcpy(bits[counter], b, strlen(b));

        counter++;
        printf("\n");

        for (int k = 0; k < counter; k++) 
        {
            printf("IP ADDRESSES:  %s", ipaddr[k]);
            printf("...Bits %s \n", bits[k]);
        }
    }   
}
```

where str is the data provided by the user, i then used some tokenization techniques to extract ip and bits.
When user press the button the program calls this function, strange thing is that my web server crashes just after getting the ip address, when i put the assign ip in the url of my browser, it crashes after couple of refreshes. If i removed the memcpy functions it works fine or if i reduce the size of gloabally declare arrays, that is ipaddr and bits to [3][17], it works fine as well.

On a side note, I am using 74KB of flash memory and 54 KB of RAM, where as total memory of MBED microcontroller is 1MB of flash and 512KB of RAM.

Comment: Your statements `strcat(htt,ur);` etc. are concatenating to somewhere in the middle of the string passed, so it is likely to overflow. Checking your string with a `printf()` statement won't reveal what else you have corrupted. At every step you should also check for NULL pointers and for string lengths against available space.

Comment: Strcat are just concatenating strings to make a url, which i want to trigger, even if i remove these lines, my webserver still crashes after couple of refreshes, the only thing which brings stability is the array size, if i change the gloabally declare arrays to ipaddrp[3][17] bits[3][17] it works perfectly fine

Comment: one more thing if i declare these global arrays in local function it works fine as well, what is the problem that i can not declare big arrays globall

Comment: Have you run out of heap space on your micro?

Comment: it has 512 KB of total ram and build details suggests I am using 58 KB of ram, it looks like a memory issue, but i dont know how i am running out of memory

Comment: Is the heap size defined by linker defaults or settings? Find out if it's a memory issue by declaring another static array, filling and checking both arrays independently from your problem. Otherwise perhaps it's time to follow the SO advice and write a complete minimal program that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Changing an array size doesn't necessarily cause a fault directly, but can simply expose it by moving an unrelated bug's side-effect from benign damage to fatal damage.